# Automated Send emails from different sender

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Created automated emails in Google Sheet Javascript and this automatically send to customer. I want the sent emails coming from sales reps NOT from me. I don't how to do it or is it possible to be done.

Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote the answer below if you feel it was useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script to achieve your target:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
  Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
  Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the first alias you set
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail('<recipient_email>','<subject_of_email>', '<message_body>', {'from': aliases[0]});
}
```

Things to do:

- Replace on <recipient_email> the recipient's email address.
- Put your subject in <subject_of_email>
- Put your message body in <message_body>

**See this link for reference in creating the script:**
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

**Setting alias through Admin Console:**

- In your Google Admin console (at admin.google.com)...
- Go to Users.
- In the Users list, find the user.
- Click the user’s name to open their account page.
- Click User information and then Alternate email addresses (email aliases).
- Click Alternate email and enter an alternate username (the part of the address that appears before the @ sign).
  Note: You can't create an alias currently assigned to someone else, either as a primary address or alias.
- (Optional) If multiple domains have been added in your Admin console, the field to the right of the @ sign is a menu listing available domains. Select a domain for the alias address.
  Note: Domains added as a domain alias don't appear in this list. A domain alias applies for everyone in your account and can't be customized for a single user.
- Click Save.

**See this link for the full documentation of adding an alias in Admin Console:**

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327

**After setting the email alias in Admin Console**, you should make sure that the alias you created is in the *Send Mail As* list. To check this, go to your Gmail->click Settings icon on the upper right corner->See All Settings->Accounts->then Look on the *Send Mail As* portion and check if your email alias is already in the list.

**[OPTIONAL] If you are just using your personal account for testing, please follow the steps below in *Setting the alias in your personal account:***

Go to your Gmail->click Settings icon on the upper right corner->See All Settings->Accounts and Import->Add another email address(Then, you can add an alias here)

Comment: Thanks so much @Monique G. I'll will try out.

Comment: You're welcome @Beginner26! I am happy it helped you! :)